# Can you do a dual flush conversion on a pull chain toilet?

Tags: toilet

I am in the process of purchasing a new house that has a pull chain toilet. It is well water with city sewage. I really like the overhead tank pull chain style toilets as I had on in my house as a kid. I also have always wanted to be environmentally conscious and liked the idea of the dual flush toilets that have two flushes one is full tank the other is partial tank so you can choose which flush to use based on the type of waste you deposited.

Since there are many dual flush converters for most toilets I was wondering if there were any conversion kits to convert a pull chain style toilet to a dual flush one. Perhaps with two chains? Would a normal conversion kit allow this with some DIY modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just had a "dual" flush device fitted to our toilet that works based on how long you hold the lever down. For a short flush just pull and let go, for a "full" flush pull and hold.

It was [one of these](http://www.evengreener.com/Shop/Water_Saving_-_Home/ECOBETA1_ecoBETA_Dual_Flush_Converter.html) which seem to be designed for UK toilets so I don't know whether you'd be able to get one in the States.

Comment: Many of the newer flapper valves have an adjustment where you turn them to adjust how much water to allow per flush.  I turn the valves to the lowest level that still flushes, which gives the same result (you can always hold them open for longer).  The only problem is when guests don't know to hold it for a full flush.

Comment: This "variable flush time" mechanism is indeed available for toilets in the US. You can also fake it by removing the air pocket from the underside of a normal toilet flapper (be careful not to damage the outer seal surface). The toilet will empty its tank only as long as the lever is held down, allowing you to flush less or more as the... situation calls for.